# Problems importing a shared script in Babel & Node

Tags: import, export, babeljs, commonjs, transpiler

I have a javascript module that needs to be imported in two different codebases:

- nodejs (8.11.3 and up NOT transpiled using babel)
- vuejs 2.5.16 (bundled by webpack & transpiled by babel)

I'm having issues exporting the file in a way both codebases can import it.

If I try to export it using commonJS like so:

```
module.exports = myFunc
```

Babel complains with `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'`

If I try to export it using commonJS like so:

```
exports = myFunc
```

Babel complains with `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined`

If I try to export it using es2015 export syntax like so:

```
export default myFunc
```

Nodejs will complain with:

```
export default reduce;
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

---

Unfortunately transpiling the complete nodejs complete is not an option. I hope this can be fixed by tweaking webpack or adding an extension or so.

Reproduce/all code:

- the repo is here https://github.com/askmike/gekko.git (branch pre-v0.6)
- the module I am trying to have shared between vue and nodejs is [here](https://github.com/askmike/gekko/blob/pre-v0.6/web/state/reduceState.js).
- to start the nodejs env: `npm install && cd web && node server`.
- to start the vue env: `cd web/vue && npm install && npm run serve`.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned **Node 8.11.3** is not transpiled using babel so I assume we can't use **babel-node** to incorporate packages using **import export** statements.

You can require the package the **commonJS** way by using

`const reduce = require('reduce');`

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to export it using commonJS since both `module.exports = x` and `exports = x` error with the messages above.

Comment: Then try using previous LTS, say **8.9.0** which can be transpiled by Babel. This is so that you can use **import export** statements because these are the two choices you have for modules.

Comment: Transpiling the complete codebase is not an option. Fortunately I have found another solution myself that works: I can use a commonJS export and tell babel to "ignore" this specific file. After that the errors above go away and babel is able to work with this file. I did such by adding the following to my `babel.config.js`: `  ignore: [
    'node_modules',
    '../state/reduceState.js'
  ]`. See this commit for more details: https://github.com/askmike/gekko/commit/ca4f4d646cabb84c0b7aff3e55d99e9d97ed6b0d